# RegExp + cyrillic in flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, haxe

Regular expression(for searching separate words in string) `"\\bword\\b"`,  seem not to work in flash if word is of cyrillic characters. If word is of cyrillic characters e.g. `"[,]word[,]"` works as it should.

Does anyone know how to solve the problem, or how to seach separate words in string?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem before and ended up with determining word boundaries explicitly in regex. In my case, search for spaces was enough, but in general list of characters to break words is almost endless.

Comment: hmm, looks like [$ ^,.;?]word[$ ^,.;?] is the only way (((